# Javascript DOM navigation

Tags: javascript, dom, ckeditor

Im writing a piece of code which allows the user to search by HTML element on a page..The user selects what element they want to search for, and then the code traverses each element highlighting them one by one..The code works fine if the user searches for one element from start to finish..If however, in the middle of one element search they switch their choice to another element the program can start failing for different reasons but primarily because the count goes out of bound e.g say im on elementArray[4] (where count = 4) for one input element.. then the user switches to table element (which may only have a total of 2 elements in the array) then the index will be out of bounds..

Can someone have a look at the code and perhaps suggest a better way of implementing?  I think i should have a seperate function to deal with the scenario when a user switches the element choice in the middle of another element search??

Thanks

```
    [{
type: 'select',
id: 'findNext',
label: 'Find next :',
isChanged: false,
labelLayout: 'horizontal',
accessKey: 'R',
items: [
    ['Form', 'form'],
    ['Input', 'input'], // Checkbox, radio, textfield, button, image
    ['Table', 'table'],
    ['Textarea', 'textarea'],
    ['Select', 'select'],
    ['Anchor', 'a'], // [option, ]
    ['Image', 'img']
],
}, {
type: 'button',
align: 'left',
style: 'width:100%',
label: 'Find Next',
id: 'findX', 
onClick: function () {
var dialog = this.getDialog();

if (typeof currentElement != 'undefined') {
    x = currentElement;
    x.removeAttribute('style'); // Remove the highlight from the current element
}

if (count != null) {
    count++;
} else {
    count = 0;
}

if (selectOptionArray == null) {
    selectOptionArray = new Array();
}

var selectOption = dialog.getValueOf('find', 'findNext'); // Get user selection e.g input, table etc
elementArray = documentNode.getElementsByTagName(selectOption);

currentElement = elementArray[count]; // Keep a reference of the current choice so the higlight can be removed on line 7
getSelection();

function getSelection() {
    if (count > 0) { // Check if there are two elements to compare
        areElementsSame();
    }

    if ((elementArray.length > 0) && (count < elementArray.length)) { // Is count out of bounds?
        nextElement(count, elementArray);

    } else {
        alert("Search complete..No elements exist.");
        count = null;
    }
}

function areElementsSame() {
    if (count >= elementArray.length) {
        count = 0;
        nextElement(count, elementArray);
    } else if (elementArray[count].nodeName == x.nodeName) {
        nextElement(count, elementArray);
    } else {
        count = 0;
        nextElement(count, elementArray);
    }
}

function nextElement() {
    if (count < elementArray.length) {
        elementArray[count].setAttribute('style', 'background-color: blue');
        elementArray[count].scrollIntoView(true);
    } else {
        alert('count is > elementArray.length, all elements navigated');
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Part of the code seems to be missing. Could you post a working version to jsfiddle, so we can try it out?

Comment: Hi bfavaretto, the code im wrtiting here is actually for a web based editor called CKEditor so i dont think it is feasible to post the other code..But what my code is doing above is:

Comment: Hi bfavaretto, the code im wrtiting here is actually for a web based editor called CKEditor so i dont think it is feasible to post the other code..But all my code is doing is, taking in an element selection (from a select box) that a user wants to find in the document, creating an array of all these elements, and then scrolling to and highlighting the element..

Comment: What i want to do is cater for the scenario where the user selects a different element, in the middle of an element search e.g user selects input element as search choice, there are 4 input elements in document..after 3rd input element is found user switches to table elements..but there is only 1 table element and hence elementArray[count] is out of bounds (count = 3, from input element search)..

Comment: Okay, retagged the question to make it clear it's about CKEditor (you didn't mention that in the post!). About the question: it seems you have to listen to the change event of the 'find' field, where you reset `count` to 0 and redefine `elementArray`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this meets all your requirements, but it's a start

Edit: [**Here's a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cay3Z/1/)

```
// call search() repeatedly to get found elements
// call it at least once with the tag name you're searching
// for - after that you can just call search() with no argument.
// If search() returns null, no element were found
// search.results() will return an array of found elements
// search.currentIndex() will return the current index
var search = (function(){
  var foundElements = [],
      lastTagName,
      currentIndex = -1;

  function next() {
    if( foundElements.length === 0 ) {
      return null;
    }
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % foundElements.length;
    return foundElements[currentIndex];
  }

  function search(tagName) {
    if( tagName && tagName !== lastTagName ) {
      foundElements = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
      lastTagName   = tagName;
      currentIndex  = -1;
    }
    return next();
  }

  search.results = function() {
    return foundElements.slice();
  };

  search.currentIndex = function() {
    return currentIndex;
  };

  search.clear = function() {
    foundElements = [];
    lastTagName = null;
    currentIndex = -1;
  };

  return search;
}());
```

---

Usage example:

```
// first time you search for a specific tag name,
// you get the first matching element back. 
result = search('div'); // find first div element

// If you search for that same tag name again,
// you'll get the next matching element
result = search('div'); // get the 2nd div element
result = search('div'); // get the 3rd div element

// you can also omit the tag name, if you just mean
// "give me the next result"
result = search(); // get the 4th div element

// if you pass a different tag name, it'll start a
// new search
result = search('form'); // get the 1st form
result = search('form'); // get the 2nd form
result = search('form'); // get the 3rd form
// etc...

// if you want to explicitly start a new search
// call search.clear()
result = search('form'); // get the 4th form
result = search.clear(); // clear the search
result = search('form'); // get the 1st form
```

Comment: Hi Flambino, thanks for answer..I will try this out..One quick question though, if this is a self invoking function should the last line not be })();  ???

Comment: @oggiemc: Actually, it makes no difference whether it's `}());` or `})();`, but jslint prefers 1st one, so that's what the shortcut in my text editor writes :) -- the only reason I can think of is that you can't accidentally leave out the invocation parens if you cut/copy the code, because if you do, the surrounding parens won't be closed and you'd get a syntax error right away… But if the invocation parens are outside, and don't get copied, js won't complain (and it'll even insert the missing `;`) so you won't see an error right away. So I'm guessing that's why jslint prefers the 1st option

Comment: Thanks flambino..A couple of other questions please :) (1) The semi colon after the search function --> return next();   };  is that a typo?  (2) In order to pass in the element that the user has selected, i assume i enter it into the double parenteses on the last line --> }('input'));  and then i change the first line to --> var search = (function(input){.. Thanks for your time..

Comment: @oggiemc: @oggiemc: 1) Nope, not a typo (but there was another typo elsewhere - fixed now). 2) No, no need to pass anything directly to the code above. When it runs, it'll simply create a function called `search`. To find something, just call `search(someTagName)` and it'll return the first result. I've added an example to my answer

Comment: Hi Flambino, When i run this code, it keeps returning the first element.. How is currentIndex ever incremented? The result of currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % foundElements.length; will always be zero since currentIndex is set to -1 in search()..Also, if the user changes the element to search for, where is this implemented in the code? Sorry, having a bit of difficulty grasping self invocationg functions..

Comment: @oggiemc: `currentIndex` is only set to -1 if you call `search()` with _a different_ tagname than last time. Otherwise it'll keep incrementing. But if you do search for something new, it'll reset so you get the first of the new results. Here's a demo with some more comments in the code: http://jsfiddle.net/cay3Z/1/

Comment: Hi Flambino, Unfortunately its not working for me..Say i pick input element, it highlights the first input element..Then i pick input again, and it highlights the same element..i think this is because each time the main search function exits all the varible values are lost out of scope such that when the function is called again, lastTagName is reset to 'undefined' and therefore the statement --> if( tagName && tagName !== lastTagName ) is true causing the following block of code to be executed each time..Could i send you my full code by email? Thanks for your comprehensive effort on this..

Comment: @oggiemc: No offense, but I'd rather not post my email on a public site. In any case, no, the values aren't lost. They're retained in scope via closure, so it works. Just run the entire self-invocating function _once_, and then use the function _it returns_ everywhere. The jsfiddle I linked to works as it should in safari and firefox - take a look at it again. If all else fails, post another question, and see if someone can figure it out

Comment: no worries, thanks anyway..just one last question though.. even if the self invocating function is contained within an outer function (this is where the self invocating function is called), will the variables still be in scope? ive ran the code a couple of times, i have an alert for the value of lastTagName in the self invocating function and each time it is 'undefined'..thanks again, and sorry for dragging the question out..this is the last one..

Comment: @oggiemc: If you place the alert inside the "inner" `search()` function, just before the `return next()` line, it should give you the right value each time you call `search()` from the outside, so to speak. As for closures, here's a simple example as a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FygGW/1/ . Hopefully it can help clear some of it up

Comment: Hi flambino, I got it working now..It was a mistake on my behalf..Thanks for your help..I wonder is it possible to get an administrator to delete all of these comments apart from the 1st 2 as i dont think they like that many comments on a topic? I will accept ur answer :) thanks again

Comment: @oggiemc: Told you it worked :) -- Nevermind all the comments. If they're a problem, an admin will figure it out by himself/herself. BTW, I don't see a checkmark by my answer yet ;)